# How to resolve floating node error in PSpice?

Tags: spice

I would like to run an AC sweep for this circuit below.

[image: Circuit]

Unfortunately the following errors occurred:

```
L_L2         N04540 0  .10976mH  
R_R3         N04968 N02907  10.7849 TC=0,0 
C_C6         N04540 N04968  7.6091u  TC=0,0 
C_C5         0 N02907  .64335u  TC=0,0 
I_I1         N04863 0 DC 0Adc AC 1Aac 
L_L3         N04858 N02907  1.989m  
L_L4         N04863 N04858  3.933m  
C_C7         0 N04858  1.099u  TC=0,0 
**** RESUMING test.cir ****
.END
ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node N04968 is floating
ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node N02907 is floating
ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node N04863 is floating
ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node N04858 is floating
```

Although I have checked the circuit several times in order to resolve the problem, I have not succeeded. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: I'm not an expert on PSpice.  From what I remember, if you connect a large value resistor (say, 10MΩ) between the floating node and ground, the node stops being floating.  A large value resistor prevents the calculation from blowing up, but doesn't affect the results appreciably.  Some variants of Spice let you set leakage resistance of components, which allows for cleaner schematic without 10MΩ resistors all over the place.

Comment: Spice packages (and any physical solvers for that matter) have to have a zero point to reference all other voltages from. It makes a starting point for the software to develop the circuit matrix similar to state space analysis.

Answer (score 5):

Your only DC path to ground would be through the current source, but you've specified zero DC current. Try putting a large resistor (100 Megaohms is fine) in parallel with the current source.

Answer (score 2):

Here ,read this:

https://www.pspice.com/incorrect-ground-symbol-may-result-floating-node-or-convergence-problems

You might try putting 1G resistor in parallel with C6 cap.

Comment: Please answer the question with more information than a link, when the link goes down the answer goes down with it.

Answer (score -3):

Put a ground on the floating nodes. i usually do it that way.

Comment: Could you also explain why this helps?

Comment: Not only explain why it helps, but how you can ground nodes in the circuit without affecting its performance.