# This circuit has floating nodes in LT Spice?

Tags: ac, transformer, ground, spice, ltspice

[image]

This is the circuit I'm working on. This circuit probably doesn't work as intended to begin with, but that's not the point.

LT Spice keeps complaining that it doesn't have a reference to ground. I get an error that says "This circuit has floating nodes."

I found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/144792/how-to-resolve-floating-node-error-in-pspice) but that didn't solve my problem.

It would be one thing to just connect a ground somewhere, but that will ruin the validity of my circuit.

The voltage source defined as MAINS in this circuit is just that...a simulation of the mains. It is a 60Hz sine wave with an amplitude of 120V. If I add a ground to it, I won't get the negative part of my wave!

The resistor connected to the voltage source is there to prevent another error being thrown about having inductors in parallel with the voltage source.

How can I keep this circuit equivalent to the real world so that I can simulate without losing half my wave from my MAINS voltage source?

Comment: I cannot see one single ground symbol in your diagram.

Comment: That's kind of my point. Where would I put it exactly? A node on the bridge rectifier acts as ground for half the cycle, but for the other half of the cycle a different node acts as ground.

Comment: I'd put the GND at the bottom line where all your resistors (R2, R4, R6, R14, R17, R12, R10, R8) are connected to.

Comment: What @Curd said is sensible and I would do that too. Nonetheless I'd like to point out that where you put your ground node in the schematic is irrelevant. LTspice will work anyway. The only difference is that the node voltages LTspice will compute will be referenced to a different node.

Comment: Why not post a link to the .asc file or post it directly? That way we can simulate it ourselves without having to draw the whole thing again.

Comment: You would also want to make sure that your voltage source is 170V peak, not 120.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In LTSpice, every node needs a path to GND.  Just tack a GND node to both your primary and secondary side (drawn in CircuitLab for simplicity):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYuNUQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: +1 not just LTSPICE, but any SPICE flavour unless they hide high-value resistors to ground inside the models. Sometimes you actually have to add (eg.  10G) fake resistors to ground to get it to work, but not in this case.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany can you give an example when you need to use a high value resistor instead of a ground node?

Comment: Something like the above where you want the ground floating and have a more realistic model of the transformer to model AC behaviour on the floating ground. There is actually a parameter in SPICE called RSHUNT (default 0 which is no resistor) that puts hidden resistors from every node to ground, you can change it to something like 1E12 and the example circuit should simulate.

Comment: I did end up adding a resistor of sorts, but to combat a different error. SPICE apparently doesn't like inductors in parallel with voltage sources without some form of ESR. I just added an internal resistance of 1e-9 to the voltage source to avoid a nasty schematic. Could you use the same internal resistance to fix the problem you're mentioning?

Comment: No. The resistor @SpehroPefhany talked about is between (isolated) "transformer" sides.